# let latex decide where to put align equations

Tags: spacing, align

I have used align to write 10 lines long equation. 
Since the align equation always appear at the current place, nearby pages are filled with too much spaces, is there a way to let align be floating so latex could decide the best position to put it?

Comment: Put them in a `figure` environment

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "nearby pages are filled with too much spaces". Are you saying that if the ten equations won't fit on the current page, an unsightly gap is left on that page and the ten equations start at the top of the next page? If not, please state what else is going on.

Comment: You can use the `\allowdisplaybreaks` directive.